# How to delete the highest value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe with 5 values per row. I need to calculate the mean of the 4 lowest values. So, I would like to delete the highest value in each row and then calculate the mean. For me, it does not matter in which column the highest value is.
example:

```
df = {"A":[78, 45, 50, 85, 63],

      "B":[52, 67, 81, 65, 83],

      "C":[67, 55, 81, 62, 58]}
```

I would like to get a column with `59 (the mean of 78, 45, 50 and 63) for A`, `66.25 for B` and `60,5 for C.`

Thanks for your suggestions so far! After trying them, I realized I need to add something.

I also have negative values. I want to exclude the highest deviation from zero, so the highest absolute value. But I need the mean of the true values, both positive and negative.
example:

```
df = {"A":[-78, 45, -50, 85, -63],

      "B":[-52, 67, -81, 65, -83],

      "C":[67, -55, 81, -62, 58]}
```

I would like to get a column with `-36.5 (the mean of -78, 45, 50 and -63) for A`, `-.25 for B (not using -83)` and `2 for C (not using 81).`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the `sum` and subtract the `max` value then divide by the number of values per column excluding the max value:

```
(df.sum() - df.max()) / (len(df) - 1)
```

Result:

```
A    59.00
B    66.25
C    60.50
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

"I need to calculate the mean of the 4 lowest values." - if you mean that in each row you choose 4 lowest elem from 5 and then calculate the mean; the easiest way to do this is to sort all rows and then take the first 4 elem - or delete the las column as you prefer.